# Where to put custom keyboard layouts in X.Org

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout

I work in a technical, multilingual field, so I have created a number of custom X.Org keyboard layouts that allow me to easily type the special symbols and foreign letters I commonly use.

Up until now I have been adding these layouts to the various language files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` (e.g., `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` for English layouts, `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ru` for Russian layouts, etc.).

The problem is that these files get overwritten whenever I update X.Org.  Of course, I want to get whatever updates X.Org makes to the other layouts; I just don't want it to overwrite my new ones.

Is there anywhere else I can put my own layouts so that they don't get overwritten by system updates?  For instance, will X.Org look for them in `/usr/local/share/X11/xkb/symbols`?

Comment: Great question left idle for 5 years. I found a similar one for Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1003404/is-there-an-official-folder-in-the-home-directory-for-storing-keymaps Not sure what system you are using though.